# react native Failed to find Build Tools

Tags: android, react-native

I want to start learning React Native and I am using WebStorm 2017.3.4 for that. I am an android developer using android studio meanwhile. When I want to run the project, I encounter this error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1
```

I checked through build.gradle file and

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
. 
.
.
```

this piece of code was there and when I want to edit this file, webstorm says this file cannot be edited and when I edit it by force and make numbers same to my android studio project(26 and 26.0.2), nothing changes.

I have searched a lot but none of solutions worked.

---

**update 1:**

in my list of sdk manager, there is no 23.0.1:
[image: sdk manager]

tnx

Comment: Install buld tools 23.0.1 on SDK

Comment: In my list of SDK manager, there is no 23.0.1 @VolkanSahin45

Comment: just 23 is enough i think. Open sdk manager. Select 'show package details' and install 'Android SDK Platform 23'

Comment: if you see my post update, 23 is already installed @VolkanSahin45

Comment: Yeah Because of my internet i didn't see the photo first when I open comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check obslute option
Then u gote this package

Comment: only check absolete and uncheck all

Comment: I did it, but all options hide doing that